# Why os.path.dirname(path) and path.split() gives different results?

Tags: python, string, character

According to [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) os.path.dirname(path) returns first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split(). But, when I try to call code below, I get another result:

```
os.path.dirname('C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder')
```

> 'C:/Polygon/id/folder'

```
'C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder'.split()
```

> ['C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder']

But, if I add one extra slash to the end of line:

```
os.path.dirname('C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder/')
```

> 'C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder'

Comment: does it still do the same thing if you have say 'C:/Polygon/id/folder/whatever' instead of double folder?

Comment: @Brent yes, result will be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `str.split()` method instead of `os.path.split()`, which instead of splitting with the `os.path.sep` delimiter, is splitting the whitespace (which there are none in your string, hence, no splits).

Observer the differences:

```
p = 'C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder'

os.path.dirname(p)    # dirname method of os.path
# 'C:/Polygon/id/folder'

os.path.split(p)      # split method of os.path
#('C:/Polygon/id/folder', 'folder')

p.split()             # split method of str object with space
# ['C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder']

p.split('/')          # split method of str object with '/'      
# ['C:', 'Polygon', 'id', 'folder', 'folder']
```

To answer your other question: the `os.path.split()` is basically the same as follows:

```
('/'.join(p.split('/')[:-1]), p.split('/')[-1])
# i.e. tuple of (everything but the last element, the last element)
# ('C:/Polygon/id/folder', 'folder')
```

So when you `split()` the `'/'` in the string, the last element becomes an empty string because nothing follows the last `'/'`.  Hence:

```
os.path.split(p)          
# ('C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder', '')

('/'.join(p.split('/')[:-1]), p.split('/')[-1]) 
# ('C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder', '')

os.path.dirname(p)      
# since it returns the first element of os.path.split():
# 'C:/Polygon/id/folder/folder'
```